# convert flv video file to m3u8 format with h264 and aac codec in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, aac

I want to convert a flv video file to a m3u8 container using AAC and H264 encoding in FFmpeg version 0.7.15. Can anyone help me on this?

I used this command to convert to the m3u8 format, but it throws an error:

**cmd:** `ffmpeg -i sample.flv -b 1104k -s 320x240 -vcodec libx264 -ab 32 -ar 24000 -acodec libfaac final_video.m3u8`

**Error:**

```
ffmpeg version 0.7.15, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 22 2013 07:22:31 with gcc 4.4.5
  configuration: --enable-libdc1394 --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-Wall -g ' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --disable-decoder=libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --extra-libs=-lgcrypt --disable-altivec --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-vis
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
  libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[libspeex @ 0x93e6c60] Missing Speex header, assuming defaults.
[flv @ 0x93e25e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 60.00 (60/1) -> 30.00 (60/2)
Input #0, flv, from 'sample.flv':
  Metadata:
    duration        : 60
    creationdate    : Wed Apr 10 17:13:05
  Duration: 00:01:00.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libspeex, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16
WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s
[NULL @ 0x93e3840] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'final_video.m3u8'
final_video.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 2):

Your FFmpeg version is too old—only recent FFmpeg has a segment muxer built in. Refer to [the documentation for more](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment). Download a [recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), or compile it from source.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.flv -c:v libx264 -b:v 1104K -c:a libfaac -b:a 32K -ar 24000 -f segment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 out%03d.mkv
```

Note that using `-ab 32` means 32 Bit/s. If you want Kilobits, use `32K` instead, and you might want to use the more unambiguous `-b:a`.

Comment: I agree with you, slhck. But the poster actually asked how to convert from .flv video to .m3u8, whereas you've told him how to convert from .flv video to .mkv video.

Comment: @Ed999 `.m3u8` is a playlist file; it does not contain any audio or video data. I told the OP how to convert from FLV to MKV indeed, but at the same time an M3U8 file is created.

Answer (score 1):

I made a medium post on this [here](https://medium.com/@mikekaufman4/how-to-stream-video-with-go-simplified-eb8244277da5) Learn more about ffmpeg options [here](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/options-51.htm.gz)

```sh
ffmpeg -i demo.flv -b:v 1M -g 60 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_size 500000 output.m3u8
```

### Let’s breakdown the command (It does a lot!  )

We have as `-i` input the demo.flv file with a video `-b:v` bitrate of 1M and `-g` set the group of pictures to 60 (default 12), `-hls_time` of 2 creates a playlist file and makes one or more segment files in time slices of 2.

Then, set `hls_list_size` to 0 so the list file will contain all the segments and return only one playlist.m3u8, and finally `hls_segment_size` of 62.5kB max (Picks minimum of segment size or segment time).

[image: stream-video-with-go]

Answer (score 0):

The format .M3U8 is **not** a valid output format.

Only a valid *container* format, such as .mp4 or .mkv, can be used to hold (i.e. "wrap around") the video and audio streams coming from the .flv file. But .m3u8 is a playlist format, which can only validly contain *text*.

You cannot convert from a video format, such as .flv, to a non-video format. It is like trying to wrap a video stream in a .pdf or .doc container: it won't work. So ffmpeg rightly throws a fit if you try to do it.